# System.PlatformNotSupportedException when connecting SignalR hub to Azure SQL database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, signalr

Why do I get a 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' in the line Groups.Add() of my hub class in the OnConnected method using an Azure SQL database?

Comment: Have you tried with a local instance of SQL Server, or on a different server (not Azure SQL)? If so, were you successful?

Comment: Probably because of this: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/799d9bc32524066344cb3656e5f28f2fd03ba9b3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer/SqlInstaller.cs#L51-L57 - check your stack trace to confirm and see what is the result of `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ( 'EngineEdition' )`